# Is $\mathcal B\leq\mathcal B'$ $\iff $ $B'\in \mathcal B'\implies B'\in \mathcal B$ an order on topology basis?

Tags: general-topology

I was wondering, Let $(X,\mathcal T)$ a topological space. Is $$\mathcal B\leq\mathcal  B'\iff (B'\in \mathcal B'\implies B'\in \mathcal B)$$ an order on topology basis ? (i.e. $\mathcal B$ is thinner tan $\mathcal B'$). Or we prefer to define such a relation as $\mathcal B'\leq \mathcal B$ ?

Comment: Yes, sure you can define a partial order $\mathcal{B} \le \mathcal{B}'$ iff $\mathcal{B}' \subseteq \mathcal{B}$ on the set of all bases of the topology $(X, \mathcal{T})$. What's your purpose with it, Zorn?

Answer (score 0):

What you have described is just inclusion (in the reversed order), and inclusion forms a partial order on the set of all basis for a topological space $(X,\mathcal T)$. In fact, if you are given any set $S$, and $T\subset P(S)$ a collection of subsets of $S$, then $T$ is naturally equipped with the partial order given by set inclusion.